# Delete data of Todo in service rather than using scope in controller

Tags: angularjs

Here's my code

```
angular.module("todoListApp", [])
.controller('mainCtrl',  function($scope, dataService){

/* updated */
 dataService.getTodos(function(response){
  console.log(response.data);
  $scope.todos = response.data;

 })

 $scope.deleteTodo = function(todo, $index){
 dataService.deleteTodo(todo, $index);
  $scope.todos.splice($index, 1);
}


})
.service('dataService', function($http){
 /* Updated */
this.getTodos = function(callback){
$http.get('../mock/todos.json').then(callback);
};
this.deleteTodo = function(todo, $index){
console.log("The todo" + todo.name + " todo has been deleted ");

};
```

I want to implement deleteTodo method in service's deleteTodo method only and not using `$scope.todos.splice` in the controller.

Any alternatives way to do this ?

**UPDATE**

I have updated the code for fetching the data. Hope it helps better to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should do all array operations in the service:

```
angular.module("todoListApp", [])
.controller('mainCtrl',  function($scope, dataService){

   $scope.deleteTodo = function(todo, $index){
     dataService.deleteTodo(todo, $index);
   }
})
.service('dataService', function($http){
self = this;
this.todos = [];

this.addTodo = function(todo){
  self.todos.push(todo)
  //more stuff
}

this.deleteTodo = function(todo, $index){
  self.todos.splice($index, 1);
  console.log("The todo" + todo.name + " todo has been deleted ");
};
```

If you want to bind your todos to some list in the view, you should bind directly to the service object:

```
$scope.todos = dataService.todos;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is have the service return the $http promise (assuming that you are using $http to do add/edit/delete operations on the todos list)
Something like this (not tested):

```
angular.module("todoListApp", [])
  .controller('mainCtrl',  function($scope, dataService) {
    $scope.deleteTodo = function(todo, $index) {
      dataService.deleteTodo(todo, $index).success(function(data) {
        $scope.todos = data;
      });
    };
  })
  .service('dataService', function($http) {
    this.deleteTodo = function(todo, $index){
      console.log("The todo" + todo.name + " todo has been deleted ");
      var url = '/todos/' + id; //whatever the url to your delete todo api is
      return $http.delete(url);
    };
  });
```

Comment: I have updated the way I fetch data - froma  json file. Your answer seems close because of the mention of promises as read on few other answers but not that clear